# Powershell delete all users in OU

Tags: powershell, active-directory, powershell-4.0

I am trying to delete all users within an OU using powershell, I have the below which gets stuck when it comes to the SAMAccount name, I want it to delete all the found users.

What am I doing wrong here please?

```
$search="OU=Staff,OU=Users,DC=Testing, DC=Local"

$deletes= Get-ADUser -SearchBase $search -filter * -properties SamAccountName | Select-Object SamAccountName 

$numusers=($deletes.count) 
echo "$numusers Users Found"

foreach ($delete in $deletes) 
{
   echo "Deleting user account $delete . . . " 
    remove-aduser -identity $delete -confirm:$false 
 }
```

This is the output. Seemingly going wrong here -- Cannot convert the "**@{SamAccountName=bbonhomme}"**

7 Users Found

```
Deleting user account @{SamAccountName=bbonhomme} . . . 
Remove-ADUser : Cannot bind parameter 'Identity'. Cannot convert value "@{SamAccountName=bbonhomme}" to type 
"Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADUser". Error: "Cannot convert the "@{SamAccountName=bbonhomme}" value of type 
"Selected.Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADUser" to type "Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADUser"."
At C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\import\getadusers.ps1:11 char:29
+     remove-aduser -identity @delete -confirm:$false
+                             ~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Remove-ADUser], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.RemoveADUser
```

Comment: you have make a loop for each  `$delete` but you ran your command with `$deletes` (with an ending S) are you suire about that ?

Comment: My mistake question updated, been trying many variations

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace the

```
$deletes= Get-ADUser -SearchBase $search -filter * -properties SamAccountName | Select-Object SamAccountName
```

by

```
$deletes= Get-ADUser -SearchBase $search -filter * -properties SamAccountName
```

Adding Select-Object implies converting ADUser "object" to "Psobject". By consequence subsequent command remove-ADuser does not recognize this type of object.

Replace also :

```
remove-aduser -identity $deletes -confirm:$false
```

By

```
remove-aduser -identity $delete.SamAccountName -confirm:$false
```

changed $deletes by $delete (you cannot specify a collection in -Identity parameter)

Comment: With the @ replaced by $ at delete.Samaccountname that worked thank you